# Button Background property not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, background

I have a button with a style in my code. The Style is in the resources of the .xaml file:

```
<Style x:Key="RoundCorner" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border CornerRadius="8" BorderBrush="#006AB6" BorderThickness="1" Name="border" >
                                <Grid x:Name="grid" >
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ></ContentPresenter>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers></ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

And here's the code for the button:

```
<Button Name="btnZ" Background="Red" Content="{Binding Z}" Grid.Column="2" Style="{DynamicResource RoundCorner}" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsButtonVisible, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

The background property for the button, in which I set the property to Red - doesn't work. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to map the `Background` of the Button to the `Background` of the inner ControlTemplate (whose the root visual is the `Border`) using `TemplateBinding` (for convenience):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Border CornerRadius="8" BorderBrush="#006AB6" BorderThickness="1" 
          Name="border"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
   />
   <!-- ... -->
</ControlTemplate>
```